# Multiple parametric or parametric and non-parametric plots on same graph

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to have

```
set size square
set parametric
set trange[-5:5]
plot ((((t-1)**2)-(4))/2),t
```

and

```
plot x-1
```

on the same graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a "normal" plot is a special case of "parametric" and you can use

```
set size square
set parametric
set trange [-5:5]
plot ((((t-1)**2)-(4))/2), t, t, t-1 t "x-1"
```

[image]

or with different ranges

```
set size square
set parametric
set trange [0:1]

# maps [0:1] -> [A:B]
p(t)= A + t*(B-A)

plot A=-5, B=5,  ((((p(t)-1)**2)-(4))/2), p(t), \
     A=-2, B=10, p(t),                    p(t)-1 t "x-1"
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set different `trange` for the different plots?(Using a different dummy variable)

Comment: @user80551 I added an example with "emulation" of different `trange'.